# Automate Photomerge in Photoshop for multiple panoramas unattended

Tags: merge, automation, photo, photoshop

I am creating panoramas using my DSLR camera and Photoshop to stitch them together. I am doing 360-degree cylindrical projections. Photoshop is brilliant at automaticaly stitching them together using PhotoMerge, but given that I have a large number of panoramas to create (hundreds) and one photo-session usually brings in about 30 of them, I am looking for a way to "automate the automation" (pun intended) -- what I need, is to tell Photoshop where the folders with the individual shots are (about 30 of them each) and have it create a panorama from each folder (using the existing files in there) and automatically save it, as a PSD with the output panorama IN that folder. So, essentially, I have folders:

P1, P2, P3, each containing files such as:

/P1/Shot01.jpg
/P1/Shot02.jpg
...
...
...
/P1/Shot30.jpg

and so on for the others, and I want Photoshop to automatically load all the Shot**.jpg in each folder, create the panorama, save it as a PSD IN the same folder, then open the other folder, do the same, etc. I don't know if there is a way to do this. What I am looking for is to have Photoshop stitch together all the panoramas, unattended... since this takes a long time (Several hours).

Any clues would be so helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the instructions above there is easy way to run the script than what is said in the document.

This is my first try to run a PS script and after struggling with it many hours (It gave me numerous error messages like file or folder not found, xxxx is not a function etc.) I found a easy way to run the script. May be I was having a fundamental mistake.

1. Download the ExtendScript Toolkit
2. Copy and paste the above script and change the Script folder path to where it is installed on your computer.
3. Save the file in your script folder (Name Automate Panaroma etc.)
4. Open the photoshop
5. Go to File-Script
6. You will see your new script Automate Panaroma
7. Click on the option and it will run nice and neat from there.